# Count how many times certain pandas row has specific column value lower than another certain pandas row across many pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I couldn't find better title for the question and it may be confusing, I'll try to explain it better with the example below.

I have the following dataframe with the possible combinations between four players:

```
players_combinations
 #   player_x   player_y
---  --------   --------
 0   player_1   player_2
 1   player_1   player_3
 2   player_1   player_4
 3   player_2   player_3
 4   player_2   player_4
 5   player_3   player_4
```

And I have the following dataframes with information about games between the players and their podium places:

```
game_1
 #   player     place
---  --------   -----
 0   player_1   2
 1   player_2   3
 2   player_3   1

game_2
 #   player     place
---  --------   -----
 0   player_2   2
 1   player_3   1

game_3
 #   player     place
---  --------   -----
 0   player_1   3
 1   player_2   1
 2   player_4   2
```

**The problem is:** I need to count how many times `player_x` has `place` value lower than `player_y` across the games dataframes. In another words, I would like to know how many times a player beat another based on their podium places.
For this example, I expect to get something like this:

```
result
 #   player_x   player_y   won        lost
---  --------   --------   --------   --------
 0   player_1   player_2   1          1
 1   player_1   player_3   null       1
 2   player_1   player_4   null       1
 3   player_2   player_3   null       2
 4   player_2   player_4   1          null
 5   player_3   player_4   null       null
```

This result dataframe tells that:

#0 row: player_1 beat player_2 one time, player_1 lost to player_2 one time.

#1 row: player_1 never beat player_3, player_1 lost to player_3 one time.

#2 row: player_1 never beat player_4, player_1 lost to player_4 one time.

#3 row: player_2 never beat player_3, player_2 lost to player_3 two times.

#4 row: player_2 beat player_4 one time, player_2 never lost to player_4.

#5 row: player_3 and player_4 never faced each other.

Comment: Can you provide your inputs in a easily reproducible format? Like `DataFrame` constructors.

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) on the data sorted by rank, then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) it with `players_combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

s = pd.Series(Counter(c for df in games for c in
                      combinations(df.sort_values(by='place')['player'], 2)))

out = (players_combinations
       .merge(s.rename_axis(['player_x', 'player_y']).reset_index(name='Won'),
              how='left')
       .merge(s.rename_axis(['player_y', 'player_x']).reset_index(name='Lost'),
              how='left')
      )
```

*NB. this uses knowledge of the implementation of `combinations` that for `['A', 'B', 'C']` will produce a specific order: `[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]`, always putting first in the combination an item that is ranked first in the original iterable.*

Output:

```
   player_x  player_y  Won  Lost
0  player_1  player_2  1.0   1.0
1  player_1  player_3  NaN   1.0
2  player_1  player_4  NaN   1.0
3  player_2  player_3  NaN   2.0
4  player_2  player_4  1.0   NaN
5  player_3  player_4  NaN   NaN
```